# Extracting data from node API and saving output

Tags: node.js

This is a bit of a continuation on a previous question, however, I believe this question is quite different from the previous one.

I am using trying to get data through a [node.js API](https://github.com/boxing/boxrec)

According to the readme the data is retrieved in JSON format.

I would like to get a list of active heavyweight boxers along with information associated with said boxers and save the output as a json which I will then clean up for further analysis.

Not sure what I am doing wrong but;
i.) I cannot print out the json output associated with said boxers as shown in the readme output (for the getRatings method) and cannot dump this data into a JSON or csv file. The output file is simply empty.

Here is my code:

```
const boxrec = require("boxrec").Boxrec;
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
const fs = require('fs');
async function getCookieJar(){
    try {
        const cookieJar = await boxrec.login('**','****');
        return cookieJar;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Login error: " + e);
    }
};
async function writeData() {
    const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
    var boxers = await boxrec.getRatings(cookieJar, {
        "division": "Heavyweight",
        "sex": "M",
        "status": "a"
    });
    const ws = fs.writeFileSync('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\testing.json', JSON.stringify(boxers));
};
try {
    writeData();
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in writeData: " + error);
}
```

If I instead simply print out boxers using console.log(boxers) this is the output that is produced:

```
i {
  '$': [Function: initialize] {
    fn: initialize { constructor: [Circular], _originalRoot: [Object] },
    load: [Function],
    html: [Function],
    xml: [Function],
    text: [Function],
    parseHTML: [Function],
    root: [Function],
    contains: [Function],
    merge: [Function],
    _root: {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {},
      children: [Array],
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null
    },
    _options: {
      withDomLvl1: true,
      normalizeWhitespace: false,
      xml: false,
      decodeEntities: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried for `console.log(JSON.parse(boxers)) `??

Comment: @Subburaj I hadn't, this returns the following message:  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: try for `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(boxers)))`

Comment: @Subburaj output is empty -> { }

Comment: Means your `boxrec.getRatings` is returning empty results, so your CSV is Also empty. Check whether its returning any data??

Comment: @Subburaj is not returning empty results as the `console.log()` of the result shows an output. The problem is that is not a plain JavaScript object that can be serialized with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @Emm Its not related to data, its related to some model. The console clearly states that its some related to model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` at the start of the output determines that is not a JavaScript plain object. Determines that is an instance of a class of type `i` (minified JavaScript), which don't works well with `JSON.stringify()`.

By looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/boxing/boxrec/blob/bee1948f9d4effd2febeb82b5d83ba4f9112b9aa/src/boxrec.class.ts#L216) and [here](https://github.com/boxing/boxrec/blob/bee1948f9d4effd2febeb82b5d83ba4f9112b9aa/src/boxrec-pages/ratings/boxrec.page.ratings.ts), you can see that what it actually returns is a `BoxrecPageRatings` instance, which is not a plain JavaScript object, but an instance that you should work on, by calling methods, accesing properties and such.

I guess that you should read source code to understand what is happening or reach their [issues](https://github.com/boxing/boxrec/issues) and ask what is happening, as the result are not JSON objects as they state in their README.

By the way, the usual way to serialize an instance in JavaScript is by accessing the properties that you like to save, because doing `JSON.stringify()` over an entire instance is not a good thing (as you noticed):

```
var boxers = await boxrec.getRatings(cookieJar, {
    "division": "Heavyweight",
    "sex": "M",
    "status": "a"
});

// I don't know what properties it has actually, but you get the point
let saveString = JSON.stringify({
    name: boxers.name,
    id: boxers.boxerId,
    weird: boxers.thing,
    list: boxers.getList().map(yay => yay.name),
    // [...] etc
});
```

Comment: I see!, makes sense, when I use the getPersonById method and access the properties I would like to see and save, this works, but not with the getRatings method so maybe the properties are different with getRatings

Comment: I see that there's a `boxers()` getter, which maps to `.boxers` property [here](https://github.com/boxing/boxrec/blob/bee1948f9d4effd2febeb82b5d83ba4f9112b9aa/src/boxrec-pages/ratings/boxrec.page.ratings.ts#L36). Try to `console.log(boxers.boxers);` and see what's there. I don't see any documentation on this so I guess that the best you can do is to read this source code and test. There's also a `.output` property which you can check. Maybe that's the JSON you want.

Comment: boxers.output seems to produce the desired output. Thank you so much!